# Why does kscript not like semicolon?

Tags: kotlin

I was playing around with Kotlin scripts and am irritated to get the following error:

script:

```
val name = "you"; println("Hello $name!")
```

error:

```
tt.kts:1:19: error: unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
val name = "you"; println("Hello $name!")
                  ^
```

If I use a line break instead of the semicolon it works. Didn't the compiler just tell me that a semicolon would be fine?!

It would be valid Kotlin code (inside a function of a .kt file).

Comment: Looks like some kind of KTS limitation for variable declaration. Something like `println("A"); println("B")` works in KTS just fine.

Comment: A strange limitation that would be. I've opened KT-27363.

Answer (score 0):

It was in fact a known bug. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/KT-24996